# reCAPTCHA module not working for subdomains in Drupal 6

Tags: 6, captcha

I am using Google reCAPTCHA https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html for pointing to domains and subdomains, with [reCAPTCHA](https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha) drupal module.

Now, personally i dont really think that it matters is it a "www.example.com" or "www.example.dev.com" if i put both of the domains inside google's recaptcha domain list.

Problem I'm facing is that on "www.example.dev.com" I see enabled recaptcha module, so i can click **I'm not a robot** and sometimes I do get message like pick fruit or a car, which is fine, but after I click login i just get page refreshed.

I have been trying things from this post as well : https://www.drupal.org/node/311538 and In settings.php, I found this section $cookie_domain = 'www.example.dev.com'; but it didn't work.

Did anyone face this before, because its really annoying for DEV sites not to have it enabled, and if i want to do some testing on them i have to go and do drush dis recaptcha and then clone to PROD version after.

It's only on **Drupal 6**, Drupal 7 is fine.